# Copy/move data from Azure Backup (recovery service vault) to a regular storage account?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We want to move all backed up data in the recovery service vault to a standard storage account for long term storage/archive, which is much cheaper.

Is there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there is no option for that, and even cannot download the backup data(if it supports downloading, then it is easy to upload the downloaded-item to storage account).

Here is a [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/256299-site-recovery/suggestions/38022367-enable-download-sql-backup-from-recovery-services) for downloading backup data from `Recovery Services Vault`, if the MS team can support this feature, then it would be easy to copy/move data to a regular storage account.